# Does PhoneGap require JQM or is that a coincidence?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

The PhoneGap examples that I'm seeing use jQuery Mobile, but I'm wondering if PhoneGap requires it, or if people are using JQM because they're (obviously) writing a mobile app?

In fact, does PhoneGap require jQuery at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me Google that for you:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20(iOS)%20-%20Xcode%203#Requirements

That is for iOS but no PhoneGap does not require jQuery.

People are most likely using jQuery mobile since they are trying to target multiple devices and JQM supports that fairly well out of the box.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Comment: Yes, that tutorial uses JQM.  Phone Gap itself does not require JQM.

Comment: Did this not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap does not require jQuery at all.

It's basically just an empty browser window without all the fluff.  You can use whatever HTML, CSS, and Javascript tricks you want as long as they're compatible with an HTML5 capable browser.

I like http://zeptojs.com/ for handling the javascript. Much more lightweight (although you lose a lot of the animations and stuff that JQuery has)